# PowerShell Invoke-Webrequest login Fail

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

We have this site that i want to log in and do a bit of automation that would get me info that I want.

first you need to like place these details below in this site

```
http://ipamtool.*****.com/menandmice/Login.htm
Host: 
Username:
Password:
```

and then once you successfully login you'll get to [this site](http://ipamtool.*****.com/menandmice/main.htm%60)

I followed [this site](https://adamtheautomator.com/invoke-webrequest/) which is really helpful however this one uses forms and the website that i'm working on doesn't, instead it has this inputFields. So I ended up on this is my code below:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://ipamtool.*****.com/menandmice/Login.htm" -SessionVariable my_session

$form1 = $r.InputFields

$form1.FindById('itsServer').outerText = 'somehost'
$form1.FindById('itsUsername').outerText = 'somedomain\someuser'
$form1.FindById('itsPassword').outerText = 'somepassword'

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://ipamtool.*****.com/menandmice/Login.htm" -SessionVariable my_session
```

my struggle is the site that I'm following uses `$form.Action` and I tried to do the `.Action` method but it looks like it's not available in mine.

How do you use `Invoke-WebRequest` to log in on a page and move on to the next one?

I need help. Thank you.

This is my error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection' to the type 'System.Uri' 
required by parameter 'Uri'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Tools\ExtractDNS\ExtractDNS.ps1:27 char:24
+ Invoke-WebRequest -uri $form1 -WebSession $my_session
+                        ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: The error you posted does not correlate with the code you posted. Did you change anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think the output posted does not really match the code above. The `-Uri` parameter requires something like `http://ipamtool.*****.com/menandmice/Login.htm` and probably not `$form1` as the error says.

Be aware that you can add `-Method 'POST'` to send data to the service. See the [documentation with Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1#examples) for more information.